# What is systematic testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have googled about testing uni and systematic testing. But I am confused what exactly is systematic testing? I’m developing a mobile app and like to know how I can approach this technique testing.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Systematic testing** is a much more exhaustive means of debugging software. The goal is to test the software against a variety inputs in order to find as many defects/errors as possible. The difficult part about systematic testing is usually coming up with the inputs/situations to test against (especially in the case of Android development, as a number of things can go wrong). Does your app work correctly after configuration changes? Do your `EditText` boxes specify the correct `inputType`? Systematic testing provides a means of uncover such errors, and often results in a more secure/robost application.

The Android team provides several tools that can automate this kind of testing (although obviously there is no guarantee that it will cover ALL of the cases). One such tool is [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html). Check out the Android developer's guide on [testing](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so you are saying that I have to install sort of software to be able to do this kind of testing? The monkeyrunner seem a good tool but it seems I have to write a Python program and I don't know Python at all. I was wondering I can use normal testing e.g logCat to determine the errors?

Comment: Can you perhaps give some sort of an exmaple how this testing techinqus are use?

Comment: Yup, you can test it however you want! The important thing is that you are exhaustive... i.e. you spend a while trying to think up every possible way a user might break your application. Then you can test your app against it and see if it behaves the way you want it to.

Comment: Here's a small list of [sample tests](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/what_to_test.html) you might perform from the Android developer's site. Another thing you should make sure you test against is properly handling user input into `EditText` boxes. For instance, if you have an `EditText` box that takes an integer, you would want to set `inputType="number"` to prevent the user from entering non-numerical characters. You would also want to make sure your `EditText` box didn't accept integers greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, as this would result in integer overflow.

Comment: Great ideas Alex thanks! I will try that, my app does have EditText boxes but how do I test it in LogCat? Where do I have to look if it's appear on the console? VDIWEA?

Comment: You should use the `Log` class to write to the LogCat. See this [**article**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant info Alex! Thanks alot.

Comment: No problem :). Like I said, the more time you spend writing apps, the more you'll recognize these sneaky ways of breaking apps... you'll get used to it in no time :D.

Comment: Can I ask you about systemtic testing - do I need to write a code for doing this sort of testing?

Comment: It your application is complex, it might be easier to perform automated testing. The Android SDK supplies a number of tools to perform automated testing, like I mentioned before. On the other hand, if your application isn't terribly complicated (which is often the case), I wouldn't think too "technically" about the debugging process. Just make sure you spend a lot of time with your app, testing it in every possible way. I would suggest giving it to others who have never used your app before as well... it provides a nice way of uncovering bugs that you hadn't thought to test against.

Comment: No it is not complex, this might sound nuisance but I know nothing abuot testing. I was wondering if I can use LogCat to do this sort of testing? Or perhaps you can be my tester? :D

Answer (score 1):

A systematic test is a test, in which

1. the setup is defined,
2. the inputs are chosen systematically,
3. the results are documented and evaluated by
   criteria being defined prior to the test